# Which PHP files should I edit for changing POSTS list and view pages?

Tags: posts

Iam totally new to WP but now I got a situation to integrate blog in my magento store for that Iam using WP-Blog now I need to edit `blogs posts List page` and `posts view page` I want o do this by editing `.php` files but I cannot understand WP structure and cannot find the exact files which are related to posts.please help me in acheiving this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tip: don't write your question in one huge sentence. You've lost me half way through and most probably many others. Please file an [edit] and reformat your sentence into smaller manageable sentences

Comment: thanks for the tip I will edit it meanwhile please help me with the answer please.

Comment: I suggest and recommendent that you start of by reading [theme development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) pages in the codex.

Comment: actually I don't have that much of time I just want posts related pages so that I can manage content like for example removing comments section from posts list page and changing date format @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how your theme is built. I strongly recommend that you read [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files) and [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Based on your comment, I would start with: `single.php`, `index.php` and `comments.php`